# make server name as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data from different sever, and the sever name might change. So I set the server name as a parameter. The idea of my sql store procedure is something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
        @ServerName
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM @ServerName.ClientDataBase.dbo.Client
END
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

The database version is sql server 2005

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL, however evil this may be:

```
exec('select * from ' + @ServerName + '.ClientDatabase.dbo.Client')
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at using Synonym(s)

Create syntax (from MSDN):

```
CREATE SYNONYM [ schema_name_1. ] synonym_name FOR < object >

< object > :: =
{
    [ server_name.[ database_name ] . [ schema_name_2 ].| 
         database_name . [ schema_name_2 ].| schema_name_2. ] object_name
}
```

Comment: Good idea- Works for a limited number of server names

Comment: It seems to me that both the CREATE SYNONYM and the sp_setnetname suggestions here might have unintended consequences with concurrency since the operations have a global effect.  That is, if two such operations overlapped, one or both of the operations might fail and leave the server configuration in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a linked server, says "BOB".

Then you could call sp_setnetname to change the underlying target server but keep the name BOB.

So your code would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
        @ServerName
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_setnetname 'BOB', @ServerName
    SELECT * FROM BOB.ClientDataBase.dbo.Client
END
```

Comment: You would need to drop the linked server too, unless you run this SP only once.

Comment: Why? sp_setnetname allows you to redefine the linked server target

Comment: this one is working except sp_setnetname requires sysadmin and setupadmin server roles

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Proc to get remove server name (domaine+instance name)

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.getRemoteName') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROC dbo.getRemoteName;
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.getRemoteName
 @id AS INT,
 @RETURN AS VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN 
 DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE
 ( id INT IDENTITY(0,1),
  VALUE NVARCHAR(100),
   instanceName NVARCHAR(100),
  DATA NVARCHAR(100))

 INSERT INTO @GetInstances
 EXECUTE xp_regread
 @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
 @KEY = 'SOFTWAREMicrosoftMicrosoft SQL Server',
 @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'

 -- order ascendant 
 -- Select * from @GetInstances -- uncomment to see all the instances that your have
 SELECT @RETURN=instanceName FROM @GetInstances WHERE id=@id ORDER BY instanceName ASC;
 SET @RETURN=HOST_NAME()+''+@RETURN;
END;
GO

DECLARE @RETURN AS VARCHAR(100);
-- get the instance number 0
EXEC getRemoteName 0, @RETURN OUTPUT;
PRINT @RETURN; 





-- 

exec('SELECT * FROM ['+@RETURN+'].RemoteDatabase.dbo.SampleTable');
```